# Scala package ith SBT - Can't find " .../immutalbe/Map"

Tags: scala, sbt

I've created a simple app that generates PageView for later Spark tasks.
I've only one scala file taht use a simple MAP
When created a package with SBT I run my class with command:

`java -cp .\target\scala-2.10\pageviewstream_2.10-1.0.0.jar "clickstream.PageViewGenerator"`

but I receive this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/collection/immutable/Map
```

What I am doing wrong?
Many thanks in advance
Roberto

Comment: My guess would be, that you have forgotten to add the scala runtime library to the class path.

Comment: I am not an expert of Scala, what should be the runtime path?

Answer (score 0):

To run it correctly you need to add Scala runtime library into your class path:

`java -cp $SCALA_HOME/lib/scala-library.jar;.\target\scala-2.10\pageviewstream_2.10-1.0.0.jar "clickstream.PageViewGenerator"`

But .. you can run your application also as:

`scala -classpath .\target\scala-2.10\pageviewstream_2.10-1.0.0.jar "clickstream.PageViewGenerator"`

when you have `scala` already in PATH

or use directly `sbt` as:

`sbt "runMain clickstream.PageViewGenerator"`

when `clickstream.PageViewGenerator` is you only application it is enough to run:

`sbt run`

or when you are in `sbt` interactive mode just type:

`> runMain clickstream.PageViewGenerator`

or when it is only application in your project it is enough to run:

`> run`